# Payara and centos compatibility

Tags: centos, payara

If we look at this link:
https://docs.payara.fish/enterprise/docs/5.20.0/general-info/supported-platforms.html

We find that payara 5.20 is compatible with redhat 5 and later and centos 6 and later

But from payara 5.21 and later
ex: https://docs.payara.fish/enterprise/docs/5.21.0/general-info/supported-platforms.html
there is no compatibility with centos but there is compatibility with redhat
so can we say that from payara 5.21 there is no compatibility with centos?

Comment: You state “there is no compatibility with Centos”. What is wrong with that statement?

Comment: I want to know if we can't use centos with payara 5.21

Answer (score 1):

I can assure you that `Payara 5.2021.10` with `Java version 11.0.19` is stable up to **CentOS 7**, with LTS support until April 18, 2023. I also believe that it works with `Payara 6`, but I haven't tested it yet.